# how stop accordion from closing after menu content click

Tags: accordion

how stop accordion from closing after menu content click

can someone please help me.
im stuck..
when i click items on sidemenu the accordion closes.
i want to navigate to pages, but keep the active accordion open after clicking on menu items.

Thanks

This is my code.

```
<nav class="accordion arrows sidebar-side sidebar-collapse sidebar-animate" id="mySidebar">
        <div class="dashbox">
            <a for="acc-close" class="box-title text-center dashboard" href="{% url 'kyoiku:home' %}">
                <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>　ダッシュボード</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dash-title">MENU</div>

        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu_item1"/>

        <section class="box">
            <label class="box-title" for="menu_item1"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>　名簿管理</label>
            <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp02010_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">隊員名簿</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dpi02040_input' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育指導資格一括入力</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dpi02050_input' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">健康診断一覧入力</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu_item2"/>
        <section class="box">
            <label class="box-title" for="menu_item2"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i>　教育管理</label>
            <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp03020_list' 1 %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育実施簿マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp03010_list' 1 0 %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育計画書入力</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp03040_list' 1 %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">新任教育実施入力</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp03040_list' 2 %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">現任教育実施入力</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp03060_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">現任教育時間一覧</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu_item3"/>
        <section class="box">
            <label class="box-title" for="menu_item3"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>　指導計画管理</label>
            <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dpi04010_input' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">指導監督計画入力</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp04020_list' 0 %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">指導監督予定一覧</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp04020_list' 1 %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">指導監督実績一覧</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu_item4"/>
        <section class="box">
            <label class="box-title" for="menu_item4"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>　苦情管理</label>
            <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:dsp05010_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">苦情処理簿</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu_item5"/>
        <section class="box">
            <label class="box-title" for="menu_item5"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>　帳票出力</label>
            <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:prn06010_print' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">帳票出力</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>


        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu_item6"/>
        <section class="box">
            <label class="box-title" for="menu_item6"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>　マスタ管理</label>
            <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01010_update' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">自社マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01020_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">支店マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01040_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">担当者マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01070_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">特例区分マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01700_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">警備業区分マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01900_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">資格マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01080_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01090_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">授業マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01100_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">科目マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01200_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育実施簿マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01300_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育指導資格マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01400_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">指導監督実施概要マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01500_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">重点指導項目マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01800_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">指導計画書マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst02000_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">隊員区分マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01050_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">得意先マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01060_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">配置先マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst02100_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">期マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst02200_input' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育設定マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01030_update' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">教育権限マスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst02300_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">コードマスタ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'kyoiku:mst01600_list' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">サブタイトルマスタ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="dash-title">SETTINGS</div>
        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu_item7"/>
        <section class="box">
            <label class="box-title" for="menu_item7"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>　アカウント設定</label>
            <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'password_change' %}" class="sidenav nav-link px-5">パスワード更新</a></li>
                    <li><a class="sidenav nav-link px-5" href="{% url 'logout' %}">ログアウト</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="acc-close"/>
    </nav>

    <!-- Sidebar/menu -->
```

how stop accordion from closing after menu content click

can someone please help me.
im stuck..
when i click items on sidemenu the accordion closes.
i want to navigate to pages, but keep the active accordion open after clicking on menu items.

Thanks

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.